# Ошибка "Cannot read property ' ' of undefined" при работе с JSON и JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Работаю с JSON через скрипт JavaScript.
JSON файл:

```
{
  "section_1" : {
    "1_1" : {
      "name" : "№1",
      "description" : "",
      "image" : "images/1_1.jpg"
    },
    "1_2" : {
      "name" : "№2",
      "description" : "",
      "image" : "images/1_2.jpg"
    }
  },
  "section_2" : {
    "2_1" : {
      "name" : "№3",
      "description" : "",
      "image" : "images/2.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

JS файл:

```
    $.getJSON('./MyJSON.json', function (data) {
        var out = '';
        for (var section in data){ // вывод всех товаров
            for (var key in section){
                out+='<img src="'+data[section][key].image+'" alt="">';
                out+='<h5>'+data[section][key]['name']+'</h5>';
                if (data[section][key]['description'] != "") {
                    out+='<p>'+data[section][key]['description']+'</p>';
                }
            }  
        }
    });
```

При загрузке страницы и обращении к значениям объектов консоль выдает следующую ошибку (скрин также приложен): `Cannot read property 'image' of undefined`. Скрин прилагается.
[image: ошибка]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка во втором цикле.

В цикле [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) в переменную сохраняется *ключ* - это обычная строка.

Таким образом `section` - Это просто строка, а не объект и на данный момент

```
for (var key in section){
```

здесь идет перебор символов строки, а не ключей в объекте.

Для решения достаточно получить объект, по которому нужно проходить:

```
for (var key in data[section]){
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Проблема решена!